# Movesense With nRF5_SDK : undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'

Tags: undefined-reference, movesense

I am in my first compilation using the accelerometer_app example. Ninja crashes in step 1. It seems to be due to a problem with the linking process. Here is the output.

```
PS G:\Cardiovelo_sur_NAS\Laboratoires\Labo_TI\Labo_Movesense\movesense-device-lib\myBuild> ninja
[1/1] Linking CXX executable Movesense
FAILED: Movesense
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\PROGRA~2\GNUTOO~1\92019-~1\bin\AR19DD~1.EXE  -W -Wall -Werror -Wfatal-errors -Wshadow -Wpointer-arith -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wunreachable-code -Wsign-compare -Wno-aggregate-return -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-function -Wno-cast-align -Wno-strict-aliasing -Wno-maybe-uninitialized -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fno-common -ffreestanding -fno-builtin -mapcs -gdwarf-3 -std=gnu++11 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions -fno-unwind-tables -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-threadsafe-statics -Wno-old-style-declaration -Wno-discarded-qualifiers -Wp,-w -Wno-write-strings -U__INT32_TYPE__ -D__INT32_TYPE__=int -U__UINT32_TYPE__ -D__UINT32_TYPE__="unsigned int" -Os -g -DWB_UNITTEST_BUILD  -Wl,--wrap -Wl,_malloc_r -Wl,--wrap -Wl,_calloc_r -Wl,--wrap -Wl,_free_r -Wl,--wrap -Wl,_realloc_r --specs=nano.specs --specs=nosys.specs -Wl,-Map -Wl,target.map -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-static -LG:/Cardiovelo_sur_NAS/Laboratoires/Labo_TI/Labo_Movesense/movesense-device-lib/MovesenseCoreLib/app-build/compiler/../platform/nRF5x/linker/gcc   -TG:/Cardiovelo_sur_NAS/Laboratoires/Labo_TI/Labo_Movesense/movesense-device-lib/MovesenseCoreLib/app-build/compiler/../platform/nRF5x/linker/gcc/appflash.ld CMakeFiles/Movesense.dir/AccelerometerSampleService.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/Movesense.dir/App.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/Movesense.dir/generated/sbem-code/sbem_definitions.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/Movesense.dir/generated/app-resources/resources.cpp.obj CMakeFiles/Movesense.dir/app-metadata/metadata.cpp.obj  -o Movesense  G:/Cardiovelo_sur_NAS/Laboratoires/Labo_TI/Labo_Movesense/movesense-device-lib/MovesenseCoreLib/lib/GCCARM/libmovesense-coreD.a  -lm  -lstdc++ && cd ."
c:/progra~2/gnutoo~1/92019-~1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: G:/Cardiovelo_sur_NAS/Laboratoires/Labo_TI/Labo_Movesense/movesense-device-lib/MovesenseCoreLib/lib/GCCARM/libmovesense-coreD.a(nrf_log_backend_serial.c.obj): in function `nrf_log_backend_serial_hexdump_handler':
E:\BuildAgent\work\939b802005569609\vendor\nRF5_SDK\components\libraries\log\src/nrf_log_backend_serial.c:446: undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'
c:/progra~2/gnutoo~1/92019-~1/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-none-eabi/9.2.1/../../../../arm-none-eabi/bin/ld.exe: G:/Cardiovelo_sur_NAS/Laboratoires/Labo_TI/Labo_Movesense/movesense-device-lib/MovesenseCoreLib/lib/GCCARM/libmovesense-coreD.a(manufacturingdata.c.obj): in function `store_pcba_string':
E:\BuildAgent\work\939b802005569609\nea\hal\manufacturingdata/manufacturingdata.c:926: undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed
```

The first error is:

> E:\BuildAgent\work\939b802005569609\vendor\nRF5_SDK\components\libraries\log\src/nrf_log_backend_serial.c:446: undefined reference to `__locale_ctype_ptr'

I installed nrfutil (version 6.0.1) on python 2.7.9 (default version on my PC).

Obviously, there is something that does not work and I need help to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OKAY. The problem was 18 "in front of the screen! I had installed the wrong version of the GNU Toolchain for ARM Embedded compiler. However, it was well written to choose the 2017q4 version.
The subject can be considered closed.